# Исправность Code Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

После установки Code::Blocks работает нормально. А вот после перезагрузки системы Code::Blocks как будто удаляется. Или не запускается.
Помогите исправить ситуацию.

**Обновление**

После перезагрузки папка с программой, становится коробкой с мусором. В ней остаются одни ярлыки. У меня стоит Windows 10. Устанавливал как все руками с сайта https://sourceforge.net

Описываю точную последовательность дейтсвий и результат. Скачиваю-устанавливаю-пользуюсь-перезагружаю ПК-папка с ярлыками-CodeBlocks нет в указанной папке. Конец. Данную последовательность повторял несколько раз. Результат один и тот же.

Comment: Речь о среде разработки [Code::Blocks](http://codeblocks.org/)?

Comment: Пока что все описанные симптомы выглядят как «Дорогие учёные! У меня который год в подполе происходит подземный стук. Объясните, пожалуйста, как он происходит» :) Что значит - как будто удаляется?

Comment: Уточните, какая у вас ОС, как вы устанавливали программу, как вы её пытаетесь запустить после перезагрузки, что означает "как будто удаляется или не запускается"? Опишите точную последовательность действий и получаемый результат.

Comment: Ну что ж вы глупые вопросы задаете... Ведь для него никаких других операционных систем кроме Windows не существует :)

Comment: @MaxZS судя по документации, там есть пакеты для Linux (для пяти разных дистрибутивов), OS X, Windows. http://codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Я Вам даже больше скажу, что под Win и Lin я использовал Code::Blocks. Поэтому могу сказать, что не только `судя по документации`... И в целом не плохая IDE, если бы ей кто-нибудь занимался. А вот перешел на другую IDE, потому что исправления и обновления у них происходят ну очень редко (раз в 3-4 года). А работать там есть над чем. Ночные сборки пробовал ставить, но быстро это желание у меня пропало из-за постоянных косяков в них. Не удивлюсь, если вопросы, периодически всплывающие о неработоспособности C::B связаны именно с этими сборками.

Comment: @MaxZS а, наверное я не понял шутку )

Comment: В последней сборке явных проблем нет. Проблема в windows 10 ВОТ [man](http://cppstudio.com/post/2650/)